# Trying to use Epoch Charts by Fastly, can't even follow the tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, epoch

I've done some cool things in javascript and html before, but I don't do enough of it to see what I'm missing here. I'm certain its something fairly simple that I'm forgetting or doing wrong.

For an upcoming project at work I want to use Epoch charts by Fastly, and I'm trying to get my feet wet but I cant get a single simple chart happening.
The code here is just taken from [Epoch's Getting Started page](http://fastly.github.io/epoch/getting-started/), and I've got all the scripts downloaded except jquery... 
I don't see why it wont work? Any answers are greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/epoch.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/epoch.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="area" class="epoch category10" style="height: 200px;"></div>
  <script>
  var data = [
  { label: 'Layer 1', values: [ {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 2} ] },
  { label: 'Layer 2', values: [ {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 4} ] }
  ];

  var areaChartInstance = $('#area').epoch({
    type: 'area',
    data: data,
    axes: ['left', 'right', 'bottom']
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: SCRIPT5009: 'd3' is undefined 
epoch.min.js, line 9 character 13  
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'epoch' 
index.html, line 22 character 3

Comment: Sorry, can't make new lines in comments I guess

Comment: Doesn't sound as if d3 has loaded properly.

Comment: Wow! Switching the script source from the minified one I downloaded to linking straight to their latest was all it took! No more errors, and the chart appears.

Comment: is this a client side library? what about this https://www.npmjs.com/package/epoch-charting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just took switching the downloaded script source for d3 to the link to their latest release...

Thanks Andy, I'm dumb!

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's work fine.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/epoch.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/epoch.min.css">


<script>
    var barChartData = [
        // First bar series
        {
            label: 'Series 1',
            values: [
                {x: 'A', y: 30},
                {x: 'B', y: 10},
                {x: 'C', y: 12},
            ]
        },
        // Second series
        {
            label: 'Series 2',
            values: [
                {x: 'A', y: 20},
                {x: 'B', y: 39},
                {x: 'C', y: 8},
            ]
        },

        {
            label: 'Series 3',
            values: [
                {x: 'A', y: 15},
                {x: 'B', y: 49},
                {x: 'C', y: 6},
            ]
        }
    ];
</script>


<div id="barChartData" class="epoch category10" style="width: 800px; height: 200px"></div>
<script>
    $('#barChartData').epoch({
        type: 'bar',
        data: barChartData
    });
</script>
```

You will have to change the links. It is quite simple, although at the beginning I was getting some problems. I wanted to put on jsfiddle.net but I couldn't point to the js and css files on github I don't know why..So I have just put the code.
Hope this help